# WPF ListView Drop getting the cell

Tags: wpf, listview

I'm trying to create a WPF dialogue to configure a workshop schedule.
On the left side there is a listview with one column for the teachers' names.
On the right side there is a listview with six columns, one for workshops,
and the other five columns for the days from Monday to Friday.

| Teacher |   | Workshop | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri |

```
A             WS-1           A   B
B             WS-2       C
C             WS-3                          B
```

The user should configure the schedule by drag and drop, e.g. teacher C teaches
workshop WS-2 on Monday.

In WinForms it was a simple job getting the drop cell, but I don't find a way 
of getting this in WPF.

Here's a section of the xaml code.

```
<ListView Name="_LV_Teacher"  
                SelectionMode="Single" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn  
              DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}"          
              Width="0"/>
          <GridViewColumn  
              DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TeachersName}"    Header="Teacher"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

<ListView Name="_LV_Schedule" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          AlowDrop="True" 
          Drop="_LV_Teacher_Drop" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn  
             DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=WorkshopId}" Width="0"/>
          <GridViewColumn  Header="Monday"/>
          <GridViewColumn  Header="Tuesday"/>
          <GridViewColumn  Header="Wednesday"/>
          <GridViewColumn  Header="Thursday"/>
          <GridViewColumn  Header="Friday"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Mark my answer as correct answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DragDrop HowTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3)

Challange was to figure out which property should be used in `DragDrop.DoDragDrop()`. As we have different `ListView` , so using `Teacher` entity itself would be meaningful. I get the source `Teacher` from left side `ListView` using `TextBlock.DataContext`. And set it as `DataContext` of the `Drop target` `TextBlock`.

Issue was , which `DataFormats` value to use for `DataContext`, so I used `IDataObject.GetFormats()`.

***Output :***

[image: Appointment Schedule Output]

See the sample application below. You can simple copy/paste.

***Window1.xaml***

```
<Window x:Class="WpfStackOverflow.MyDragDrop.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfStackOverflow.MyDragDrop"
        Title="Window1" Height="472.557" Width="675.564">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="123*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="380*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListView Margin="10,31,10,226" ItemsSource="{Binding TeacherData}">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="TbKey" TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="Teacher_LeftButtonDown"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="DragEnter" Handler="Teacher_DragEnter"/>

                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Teachers" Width="75">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="{Binding View.Columns[0].Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                                               Style="{StaticResource TbKey}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AppointmentData}" Margin="13,31,10,226" Grid.Column="1" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="TbKey" TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="WeekDay_LeftButtonDown"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="DragEnter" Handler="WeekDay_DragEnter"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="WeekDay_Drop"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonDown" Handler="WeekDay_MouseRightButtonDown"/>

                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>                    
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Workshop" Width="75">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Workshop}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn x:Name="ColMon" Header="Mon" Width="45">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Mon, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="{Binding Name}" Width="{Binding View.Columns[1].Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                                               Style="{StaticResource TbKey}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn  Header="Tue" Width="45">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Tue, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="{Binding Name}" Width="{Binding View.Columns[1].Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                                               Style="{StaticResource TbKey}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn  Header="Wed" Width="45">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Wed, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="{Binding Name}" Width="{Binding View.Columns[1].Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                                               Style="{StaticResource TbKey}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn  Header="Thu" Width="45">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Thu, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="{Binding Name}" Width="{Binding View.Columns[1].Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                                               Style="{StaticResource TbKey}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn  Header="Fri" Width="45">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Fri, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="{Binding Name}" Width="{Binding View.Columns[1].Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                                               Style="{StaticResource TbKey}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding AppointmentData}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="13,243,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Worskhop" Binding="{Binding Workshop}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mon" Binding="{Binding Mon.Name}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tue" Binding="{Binding Tue.Name}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Wed" Binding="{Binding Wed.Name}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Thu" Binding="{Binding Thu.Name}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fri" Binding="{Binding Fri.Name}" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,222,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Real time display of workshop schedules" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="325"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Right Click to remove appointment" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="325"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

***Window1.xaml.cs***

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfStackOverflow.MyDragDrop
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = vm;
        }

        #region WeekDay
            private void WeekDay_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
                    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
            private void WeekDay_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
            {
                ((TextBlock)sender).DataContext = e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0]);
            }
            private void WeekDay_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                (sender as TextBlock).DataContext = null;
            }
        #endregion

        #region Teacher
            private void Teacher_LeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)sender;
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(tb, tb.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
            private void Teacher_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Serializable))
                    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
        #endregion            
    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ObservableCollection<AppointmentRecord> _records = new ObservableCollection<AppointmentRecord>();
        public ObservableCollection<AppointmentRecord> AppointmentData { get { return _records; } }

        ObservableCollection<TeacherRecord> _teacherRecords = new ObservableCollection<TeacherRecord>();
        public ObservableCollection<TeacherRecord> TeacherData { get { return _teacherRecords; } }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            TeacherRecord trecord1 = new TeacherRecord() { Name = "A" };
            TeacherRecord trecord2 = new TeacherRecord() { Name = "B" };
            TeacherRecord trecord3 = new TeacherRecord() { Name = "C" };
            TeacherData.Add(trecord1);
            TeacherData.Add(trecord2);
            TeacherData.Add(trecord3);

            AppointmentRecord record1 = new AppointmentRecord() { Workshop = "WS-1", Mon = TeacherData.FirstOrDefault((t) => { return t.Name == "A"; }), Tue = null };
            AppointmentRecord record2 = new AppointmentRecord() { Workshop = "WS-2", Mon = null, Tue = TeacherData.FirstOrDefault((t) => { return t.Name == "C"; }) };
            AppointmentRecord record3 = new AppointmentRecord() { Workshop = "WS-3", Mon = null, Tue = null, Wed = TeacherData.FirstOrDefault((t) => { return t.Name == "C"; }) };            
            AppointmentData.Add(record1);            
            AppointmentData.Add(record2);
            AppointmentData.Add(record3);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }    

    public class TeacherRecord
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppointmentRecord : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        string _workshop;
        public string Workshop
        {
            get { return _workshop; }
            set
            {
                if (_workshop != value)
                {
                    _workshop = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Workshop");
                }
            }
        }

        TeacherRecord _mon;
        public TeacherRecord Mon
        {
            get { return _mon; }
            set
            {
                if (_mon != value)
                {
                    _mon = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Mon");
                }
            }
        }

        TeacherRecord _tue;
        public TeacherRecord Tue
        {
            get { return _tue; }
            set
            {
                if (_tue != value)
                {
                    _tue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Tue");
                }
            }
        }

        TeacherRecord _wed;
        public TeacherRecord Wed
        {
            get { return _wed; }
            set
            {
                if (_wed != value)
                {
                    _wed = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Wed");
                }
            }
        }

        TeacherRecord _thu;
        public TeacherRecord Thu
        {
            get { return _thu; }
            set
            {
                if (_thu != value)
                {
                    _thu = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Thu");
                }
            }
        }

        TeacherRecord _fri;
        public TeacherRecord Fri
        {
            get { return _fri; }
            set
            {
                if (_fri != value)
                {
                    _fri = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Fri");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to AnjumSKhan for the excellent answer!
I've implemented it into my application, and it works fine. Unfortunately, I got another problem.
Because my data are retrieved and stored in a database, I added two variables:
- int iTeacherId to class TeacherRecord (first column with width 0 in the teacher's Listview), and
 
- int iWorkShopId to class AppointmentRecord (first column with width 0 in the AppointmentData-Listview)
Therefore, beside the teacher's name, e.Data in WeekDay_Drop now also contains his Id.
But how do I get the corresponding workshop Id in order to save appointment in Tab_Workshop in the database.
(The teacher's name and Id are in Tab_Teacher, a different database table.)

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, mark it as correct answer. And ask separate questions for separate issues. If you want me to have a look at your question, mention me as @AnjumSKhan in the comment of your question, that will notify me.

Comment: Sorry, now I got it! Of course, class "AppointmentRecord" provides all the needed information!

Comment: Mark my answer as correct answer using a small right mark, if my answer helped u.